# Sending an array from javascript to php and then save as .json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

**Problem**

I am sending an array to PHP and then create a data.json to store it in.
The data.json does get created but the output is Null.

I am sure I am doing something wrong but i don't have a clue what. I've been staring at this code for about 2 hours, looked over a lot of answered questions here on SO but nothing worked.

I could use a fresh pair of eyes on this. I am fairly new to programming and especially webdev so I apologise beforehand.

Thanks in advance!

**Array i send to PHP**

```
[
  {
    "mainTitle": "workplace",
    "mainImage": "dog.png"
  },
  {
    "objAudio": "1.mp3",
    "objImage": "1.png",
    "objText": "Number 1",
    "objLocation": {
      "X": 49,
      "Y": 127
    }
  },
  {
    "objAudio": "2.mp3",
    "objImage": "2.png",
    "objText": "Number 2",
    "objLocation": {
      "X": 124,
      "Y": 117
    }
  }
]
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"toJSON.php",
    data: {data : jsonString},
    cache: false,
    succes: function(){
        console.log("Saved!");
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$superArray = $_POST['data'];
$path  = "json/data.json";
file_put_contents($path, $superArray));
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST); what does it contain?

Comment: How is `jsonString` created?

Comment: You're not doing any checking along the way, and `success` is misspelled in your ajax. Log your jsonString before you send it, dump/log your POST data in your php, and check for the return value of file_put_contents.

Comment: the easiest way is to check the console then XHR requests and see how request looks like and what is response. Also as @aynber noticed you misspelled "success" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure your `jsonString` is in `json` format. Then try this:

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'toJSON.php',
      data: {json: JSON.stringify(jsonString)},
      dataType: 'json'
}).done( function( data ) {
    console.log('sent');   
})
.fail( function( data ) {
       console.log('fail');
});
```

**PHP**

```
result = json_decode($_POST['json']);
var_dump(result);
```

Now if you want to save it to your file:

```
$path  = "json/data.json";
file_put_contents($path, json_encode($_POST['json']));
```

OR `Serialize` like:

```
file_put_contents($path, serialize($_POST['json']));
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it!